# let $a_{n}=n(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n-1})$, $n\geqslant 2$, $a_{1}=1$. Find $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

let $a_{n}=n(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n-1})$, $n\geqslant 2$, $a_{1}=1$. Find $a_{n}$

**My Approach:**

so I thought, since this is a homogeneous relation, I expanded the expression and wrote the characteristic equation of the same, since that was $n(x^1+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$. So I substituted the values of $n=2$, and my answer was $n(n-1)$ which is wrong.

EDIT: I cannot use the characteristic equation since the coeff is not constant

Comment: It is incorrect to use the characteristic equation. The coefficient is not a constant function.

Comment: This is not linear for two reasons: The factor $n$ is not constant. There is such a thing as linear recurrence equations with polynomial coefficients, but it's not that either, because $a_n$ may only depend on a fixed number of previous values.

Comment: I see, there are many flaws in my solution. I have just started with recurrence problems, can you give me a hint? @Milten

Comment: I don't believe this has an obvious, simple form.  It does have a closed form...namely $a_n=n\times \lceil \frac {n!}2\rceil$ but this seems hard to guess (for $n≥2$ you can drop the ceiling).   Well, dividing by $n$ is clearly a good start and then note that  what you have left  is half the factorial.

Comment: thanks a lot @MatthewvanEerde

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/976943/620957). Once you know the closed form of your recurrence, that question will help prove it.

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A074143 - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjEZyx4h1GQ in particular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx3lh8aDPT4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
&{a_n} = n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\right)\\
\implies &{a_n}=n\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}+a_{n-1}\right)\\
\implies &\frac{a_n}{n} = \left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)\times n\\
\implies &\frac{a_n}{n\cdot n!}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)\cdot(n-1)!}=\dots=\frac{a_2}{2\cdot 2!}=\frac12\\
\implies &\boxed{a_n = \frac{n\cdot n!}2}\qquad\forall n\ge 2
\end{align}

Comment: I think it should be: $a_n=n(\frac {a_{n-1}}{n-1}+a_{n-1})$

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Thank you @Ritam_Dasgupta

Comment: Moreover $\frac {a_n}{n}=\frac {n a_{n-1}}{n-1}$...where'd the factorial come from?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta, Fixed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ we have

$$
a_n = n S_{n-1} = n(S_n-a_n) = nS_n - n a_n\Rightarrow (n+1)a_n = n S_n
$$

so

$$
a_n = \frac{n}{n+1}S_n = n S_{n-1}
$$

and finally

$$
S_n = (n+1)S_{n-1},\ \ S_1 = 1
$$

and

$$
a_n = n\frac{n!}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{a_n}{n} = a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{n-1}= (a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{n-2}) + a_{n-1} = \frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}+a_{n-1} = n\cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}$$

which is valid for $n\ge 3$ (notice that it's not valid for $n=2$ because we used $a_{n-2}$).

Then $$\frac{a_n}{n}= n\cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}=n(n-1)\cdot \frac{a_{n-2}}{n-2}=\cdots = n(n-1)\cdots 3\cdot \frac{a_{2}}{2} = \frac{n!}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$a_1=1$$
$$a_2=2(a_1)=2$$
$$a_3=3(a_2+a_1)=9$$
$$a_4=4(a_1+a_2+a_3)=48$$
$$a_5=5(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)=300$$

Plugging this into OEIS gives [A074143](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C9%2C48%2C300&language=english&go=Search), where Bakare Gatta Naimat indicates that it maintains the general rule for $n\geq 2$ of $a_n=\frac{n(n!)}{2}$.

Comment: I am sorry, this is a question from a test, where we aren't allowed in electronic devices. Can you give the reasoning for the same?

Comment: On a test you wouldn't be able to just search OEIS, but you still should be able to notice that sum of the first $n$ terms follows the pattern $1,3,12,60$, which is half of $(n+1)!$.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

a(n) = n(a1+a2+a3....an-1)
So,
a(n+1) = (n+1) ( a1+a2....an) .
But a1+a2+...an-1=a(n)/n , from previous statement.
a(n+1) = (n+1)((a(n)/n )  +   an)
Rearranging we get:
a(n+1)/a(n) = (n+1)^2/n
On repeated multiplication starting at n=2 under the constraint that a(2)=2, we get,
a(n+1) = (n+1)*(n+1)fac/2
Which implies,
a(n) = (n)(nfac)/2
This is a general strategy used in sequence , in which we relate a(n+1) and a(n) using definition of the sequence and in most cases we get a telescoping sum or product . In this case a telescoping product.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the answer and you may look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the help.